# Conditional formatting of rows alternating at 4 rows at a time?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

For example, row 1-4 would have red background, row 5-9 would be blue, then 10-13 would be back to red, etc

all the tutorial I found only covers alternating each row.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `MOD` of 8 rows 4 times while each time you offset it by one row like:

```
=NOT(MOD(ROW(A1:A), 8))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

```
=mod(row()-1,8)>3
```

with a default fill colour of red.

[image]